# Can you easily take a C++ project back and forth between Qt Creator and Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, unit-testing, qt-creator

I have an application I've been wanting to build for almost a year now. I studied programming in high school and college (BS IT) and find it relatively easy. The hard part for me has been the rest of the software development life cycle. They don't seem to teach that as much in school.

I'm trying to reach as many platforms as possible. I started coding in JavaScript (with the intent to use PhoneGap), but local storage seems tedious and I decided to lean more towards application development than web development. Then I started over with Mono and C# and it was great fun and easy. Then I discovered the price tag and I can't afford to buy Xamarin. So, I think, I want to try C++ and Qt. Qt4 and Necessitas currently allow for Android and Qt5 is supposed to include iOS and Android sometime this year (plus all the desktops and loads of embedded systems).

Now I'm struggling with the idea of unit testing. The Nunit tests for C# were super easy to learn and run in both Visual Studio and MonoDevelop. C++ unit testing seems a little tougher, but I want to be Agile and use TDD. Qt Creator, however, as far as I can tell does not support automated unit tests. Eclipse does have automated unit tests with the CUTE plugin, but the Qt designer plugin for Eclipse has been abandoned. That probably won't help for mobile GUI design as Digia is still working in that arena and the old plugin was made by Nokia.

I think I want to put all of my code (OOP classes) in one library, put all of my unit tests in another library or project, and then create another project for the app/main/GUI of each platform that I aim to develop for. I'm using free/open licensing, so I'd start a project on SourceForge or something using Git. What I'm thinking is that I could use Eclipse to write the code and tests. When I need to do some GUI stuff, push the changes, close Eclipse, open Qt Creator, pull the work I just did in Eclipse and then start playing with the GUI.

Does anyone do this? Could this work? Is this madness? Better ideas?

p.s. stackoverflow is already warning me that this question appears subjective and is likely to be closed. I'm not looking to start a debate. I'm just wondering if this idea could work and if there is anything else along these lines immediately coming to mind that I have missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Qt Designer even if eclipse doesn't have a plugin for Qt that will automatically open Qt Designer for you when you open an .ui file.
I understand that you only want to edit .ui files with the designer.
So the workflow would be
Edit code in eclipse, open Qt Designer from wherever it was installed, open the .ui file, edit stuff, save it, continue in eclipse.

Like.. it's not that the designer only works with an eclipe plugin or visual studio add-in. The only thing the plugin does is open the Designer for you.

Comment: Ahh, so Qt Designer rather than Qt Creator. No matter. I installed Eclipse Indigo, CDT, Boost & the CUTE plugin. I have no option for creating unit tests. I seem to have all the prerequisites. One post somewhere said to try 'sudo eclipse -initialize', which worked for me when the CDT wasn't showing up, but it's not helping for CUTE. I think I'm giving up on unit tests for now before I end up putting my fist through my monitor. I'm just gonna go back to Qt Creator and write code for now and hope that someday the solution for automated unit testing comes to me. Thank you for your time, though.